# Left navigation drawer reusable across all activity?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have created a Left navigation drawer in Xamarin android now the thing is that I want to reuse same navigation drawer across all activity instead of copy pasting same navigation code to all activity.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Use fragments not activities https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/fragments/

Comment: @DanielP On an activity we have to create a left drawer which is working fine now the issue is that its only available on the activity on which we have creat it. We have multiple activities on which we want drawer to appear so what to reuse the code.

Comment: @G.hakim do you mena to say that insted of creating a navigation left drawere on activity I should create it on an fragment and then reuse taht fragment on all activity?

Comment: No my friend what i mean is when you create a navigation drawer you create an activity and then you dont need activities you just have to use fragments all the way, and in case you need another activity for some or the other reason then you have no option but to recreate a nav drawer